# Who wrote/recorded this Chinese parable about a deer trained not to fear wolves?

Tags: identification-request, chinese-language

It was a Chinese writer or philosopher, probably pre-1900.

Basically, a man captures a deer and a wolf and keeps them in his garden/compound. He trains the wolf not to attack the deer. The deer unlearns its fear of wolves, then escapes the compound and is eaten by wild wolves.